# Oracle date format delete query considering the timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, timestamp, iso8601

a question about date-time oracle data types:

We suppose that we have a `Oracle` database.

We suppose that we have a table with a field `'timestamp with timezone'`.

When I insert some rows into this table I have the `date in ISO-8601 format`.

My server is located in **America**.

My question is:

When should I remove rows that have a date that has passed, I have to consider the timezone?
I'm wondering: If I remove a row that has an expired date for the timezone of the server, this date may still be valid for other timezones?

how can I handle this? I would like to point out that the cancellation is via cronjob on the server (so always with the server side timezone)

Answer (score 0):

In the database base there is only one time zone - the system time zone.

When a user from a different time zone select the data from the table he sees the date and time adjusted to his time zone.

You can delete the data based on your local time zone but will it fulfill the business requirements? The best way to do that is to test it using the alter session command, i.e.:

alter session set time_zone = '-05:00';

Create a test table, insert a data from the different time zones and check which conditions apply.